# Publish/Update post is changing image links from file url to post url

Tags: functions, filters, images, editor, save-post

I've written a filter to wrap images included in posts with figure tags and their captions with figcaption tags. I turned off the visual editor so that it doesn't strip out all the html from the images.

That all seems to work fine until I publish or update the post. At this point the link to the full size image gets changed to `/sitename/post-type/post-title/attachment/attachment-title/`
where before it was `/sitename/assets/filename.jpg`

Can anyone help suggest why this is happening?

Here is a link to [the filter code on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/fC4cLL6Y)

Comment: The problem was down to my use of `rel="attachment"` in the anchor, with this removed the editor allows the link to remain pointing to the file url and not the attachment.

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer so it is more in line with site mechanics and your question doesn't haunt site as unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was down to my use of `rel="attachment"` in the anchor, with this removed the editor allows the link to remain pointing to the file url and not the attachment.

Comment: Please mark your question as _answered_.